# Keras Callbacks log information for each step

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am having difficulties to log/append observations returned for each step of an episode of a reinforcement learning model using the Keras Callback function when testing a trained model. Below is my attempt that is not working.

```
class step_logger(Callback):
def __init__(self):
    self.observations = {}
    
def on_step_end(self, step, logs):
    """ Update statistics of episode after each step """
    self.observations[step].append(['observation'])

dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=2, visualize=False, callbacks=[step_logger()])
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: why are you returning the append operation?

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow because I am not so good at this coding stuff yet. Again, I want to append or log each return from each step function in the episode while testing. I just have no clue how to formulate that.. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, instead of apppending it to an array write it on a external text file ( my understanding is that you are not going to work on this SOE, it's just for info) so instead of appending it you will write a new line on the text file at the end of every step

Answer (score 1):

consider this idea:

```
class print_test_Callback(Callback):
  def __init__(self, textpath):
    self.textpath = textpath

  def on_step_end(self):
    test=self.observation_space
    with open(textpath, 'a') as writefile:
      with redirect_stdout(writefile):
        print("test")
        writefile.write("\n")
```

this way it will write on an external text file, with this even if you interrupt the training you will still have all the data

you will pass him the path like this.

```
print_test_Callback(textpath=textpath)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps with saving the outcome! However, my issue is how to formulate a function that returns the information from each step performed during testing/training. I have tried to re-write my problem to clarify this.